# Async Azure SQL long request

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, azure

I'm trying to do a defragmentation of an SQL database from my frontend. All works fine with a small database because the query takes a small amount of time but when the size of the DB is larger, this process takes much more time and I get a timeout error. Also, I have a problem with the Azure SQL Server Timeout. So, what I heard I should do is to run an asynchronous task that will do the work on my front end, put in some spinner so the user would know there is a process in progress. And periodically check the task status. But I have no idea how to do that...
Maybe someone can help with some guiding points how to change my existing code which looks like that:

What I have now is the ajax function:

```
function defragmentDB() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/GetDbDefragmentation",
                type: "GET",
                timeout: 360000,
                $("#loading-overlay").show();
                //beforeSend: function () {
                //    $("#loading-overlay").show();
                //}
                beforeSend: function () {
                    // Show spinner here
                    $("#spinner").show();
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    // Hide spinner here
                    $("#spinner").hide();
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    // Hide spinner here
                    $("#spinner").hide();
                    if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                        alert('Failed from timeout');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

that calls GetDbDefragmentation:

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("GetDbDefragmentation")]
        public IActionResult GetDbDefragmentation()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = RunDbDefragmentation();
                return new JsonResult(SettingsResultModel.Success(result));
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return new JsonResult(SettingsResultModel.Error(ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

And DB request code:

```
public IList<string> RunDbDefragmentation()
        {
            var result = new List<string>();

            var selectQuery = DEFRAGMENTATION_QUERY;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
            {
                List<string> infoMessages = new List<string>();
                connection.InfoMessage += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    foreach (SqlError error in e.Errors)
                    {
                        string message = error.Message;
                        infoMessages.Add(message);
                    }
                };
                connection.Open();

                var selectCmd = CreateSqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

                using (var reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var value = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }

                return infoMessages;
            }
        }
```

SQL query is like that:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255) 
                DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
                (
                    SELECT '[' + IST.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + IST.TABLE_NAME + ']' AS [TableName]
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IST
                    WHERE IST.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                ) 
                OPEN TableCursor
                FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
                BEGIN
                    PRINT('Rebuilding Indexes on ' + @TableName)
                    Begin Try
                    EXEC('ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @TableName + ' REBUILD with (ONLINE=ON)')
                    End Try
                    Begin Catch
                    PRINT('Cannot do rebuild with Online=On option, taking table ' + @TableName+' down for doing rebuild')
                    EXEC('ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @TableName + ' REBUILD')
                    End Catch
                    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
                END 
                CLOSE TableCursor
                DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```